# Contributing to DefinitelyTyped repo

Tags: open-source, definitelytyped

I'm trying to make my first contribution to DefinitelyType repo
but vscode shows me this eslint error in every .ts files in this repo:

`Parsing error: Cannot read file: [folderPathInMyLocalMachine]/definitelytyped/tsconfig.json`

There are a few stackoverflow posts advising to change "project" path in "parserOptions", eslintrc.json in root repo, but I feel like no setups should be changed in this repository because it has been structured and used by many developers.

Surely, I've tried to restart vscode a few times, please let me know if you have any advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by turning off VScode eslint plugin  by glancing this post:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/61764